# Add extensions to contacts using Python and Microsoft Graph

Tags: python, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to add extensions to contacts using Microsoft Graph but I keep getting 500 errors back.

I think it is something to do with the token but I just can't work it out.

I've tried all methods but none work, I can basically go between 400, 405 and 500 errors. I'm assuming I'm close once I hit a 500 error.

All permissions are correct within azure.

Within the header I've tried the following for the token:

```
token
token['access_token']
token['id_token']
```

All three bring back a 500 error.

I've tried two ways of adding the extension, globally for all contacts and for a single contact.

Single contact (I'm printing so I can see the error):

```
def new_field(token,field):
    graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
    contacts = graph_client.get('{}/me/contacts/'.format(graph_url))
    contacts = contacts.json()
    contacts = contacts['value']
    for contact in contacts:
        id = contact['id']
        url = '{}/me/contacts/{}/extensions'.format(graph_url,id)
        payload = {
            '@odata.type' : 'microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension',
            field : None   
        }

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer, {}'.format(token),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

   print(graph_client.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers))
```

Global:

```
def new_field(token,field):
    graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
    url = '{}/me/contacts/'.format(graph_url)
    payload = {
        '@odata.type' : 'microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension',
        field : None   
    }

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer, {}'.format(token),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    print(graph_client.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers))
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Microsoft has no documentation when it comes to using graph for contacts!

************************* UPDATE ***************************

I can now get a 201 created response!

However it doesn't actually seem to create anything.... is there a delay?? I can also only get this working on a contact by contact basis, not globally.

here's the code that I have now:

```
def new_field(token,field):
    graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
    contacts = graph_client.get('{}/me/contacts/'.format(graph_url))
    contacts = contacts.json()
    contacts = contacts['value']
    for contact in contacts:
        id = contact['id']
        url = '{}/me/contacts/{}/extensions/'.format(graph_url,id)
        payload = {
            '@odata.type' : 'microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension',
            'extensionName' : field,
            'value' : 'hello'
        }

        headers = {
            'authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(token),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        print(graph_client.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding extensions is on a contact-by-contact basis. There is no way to create an extension globally and have it apply to all contacts.

There is no delay, the extension should be there immediately. You have to use Graph to get it back though, it doesn't show up in any Outlook UI. You can get the extension on a specific contact like:

```
GET /me/contacts/{contact-id}/extensions/{extension-name}
```

You can also ask for your extension to be included back in results when listing contacts like:

```
GET /me/contacts?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq '{extension-name}')
```

We do have [documentation on contacts with Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/outlook-contacts-concept-overview). The [contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource page is a good place to start. [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer) is also really handy for playing around with this stuff and getting a feel for how it works.

Comment: Great thanks for that! Yeah sorry I know there are examples, just none for python.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to create contact groups using graph?

Comment: You can [create contact folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-post-contactfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), is that what you mean?

Comment: No, distribution groups. You can't do it, only for org contacts. Which is pretty annoying